# Chrome App - Webview - не работают кнопки back и forward

Tags: webview, chrome-app

Не работают стандартные кнопки `back` и `forward` внутри `webview` приложения для хрома. При этом `backspace` и `Shift+backspace` работают исправно.
Как можно разблокировать стандартные кнопки? В `permissions` манифеста не нашёл.
Не хотелось бы создавать дополнительные элементы управления со скриптами, костылями и прочими.

Answer (score 1):

Кроссбраузерное решение всё-равно предполагает использование `<webview>.goBack()`